# plotting a spherical surface in matplotlib

Tags: vector, matplotlib, 3d, surface

What is the simplest and most efficient way to plot a spherical surface of a lens?[image]

Suppose I know the radius, the aperture radius, how do I plot the surface shown in the diagram in 3D space? It's just like the surface of a lens. Since I will be adding other surfaces or lines to the same plot, speed may be an issue as well.

Comment: Can I ask why do you want to have a schematic of a lens in 3D?